# How to hide the scrollbars on a vaadin-grid?

Tags: vaadin-grid, vaadin-elements

I want to hide both scrollbars (x and y) on the `vaadin-grid` but I cant find a working solution for that. I tried to set

```
overflow = hidden
```

on the `vaadin-grid`, `vaadin-grid-outer-scroller`, `vaadin-grid-scroller`, `#table`, `#scroller`, and many more but nothing seems to have a effect.

I want the scrolling to be enabled but I do not want the ugly scrollbars to be shown. How can I avoid them?

- vaadin-grid version: 5.0.0-beta1
- I use polymer 2.5
- I want to use css to handle the styling using a custom theme:

  ```
  <dom-module id="my-custom-grid" theme-for="vaadin-grid">
  <template>
      <style>
          :host([theme~="my-custom-grid"]) {
              --color-grey-row-selected: #f7f6f6;
              --color-grey-row-salesrank: #e6e6e6;
              width: 600px;
              border: none;
              margin: 0 auto;
          }

          :host([theme~="my-custom-grid"]) [part~="cell"]:not([part~="details-cell"]) {
              border-top: none;
          }

          :host([theme~="my-custom-grid"]) [part~="cell"] ::slotted(vaadin-grid-cell-content) {
              padding: 0;
          }

          :host([theme~="my-custom-grid"]) [part~="header-cell"]:nth-child(1n) {
              min-height: 0;
              min-width: 398px;
              max-width: 398px;
              height: 52px;
              padding: 19px 11px 17px;
              border-top: none black;
              border-bottom: none black;
              font-size: 14px;
              font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
              font-style: normal;
              font-weight: 400;
          }

          :host([theme~="my-custom-grid"]) [part~="header-cell"]:nth-child(2n) {
              min-width: 104px;
              max-width: 104px;
              padding: 20px 12px 17px 12px;
              background: #c7c7c7;
              font-size: 13px;
              font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
              font-style: normal;
              font-weight: 500;
          }

          :host([theme~="my-custom-grid"]) [part~="header-cell"]:nth-child(3n) {
              min-width: 98px;
              max-width: 98px;
          }

          :host([theme~="my-custom-grid"]) [part~="row"] {
              border: none black;
          }

          :host([theme~="my-custom-grid"]) [part~="row"][selected] [part~="body-cell"] {
              border-right: none black;
              border-left: none black;
          }

          :host([theme~="my-custom-grid"]) [part~="body-cell"] {
              min-height: 0;
              height: 46px;
              border: none black;
          }

          :host([theme~="my-custom-grid"]) [part~="body-cell"]:nth-child(1n) {
              min-width: 398px;
              max-width: 398px;
              padding: 13px 13px 12px;
              border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
              font-size: 14px;
              font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
              font-style: normal;
              font-weight: 400;
          }

          :host([theme~="my-custom-grid"]) [part~="body-cell"]:nth-child(2n) {
              min-width: 104px;
              max-width: 104px;
              padding: 12px 6px 13px;
              text-align: right;
              background: rgba(230,230,230,0.4);
              font-size: 12px;
              font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
              font-style: normal;
              font-weight: 500;
          }

          :host([theme~="my-custom-grid"]) [part~="body-cell"]:nth-child(3n) {
              min-width: 98px;
              max-width: 98px;
              padding: 10px 17px 12px;
              font-size: 12px;
              font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
              font-style: normal;
              font-weight: 500;
          }

          :host([theme~="my-custom-grid"]) [part~="body-cell"]:nth-child(3n) {
              font-size: 12px;
              font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
              font-style: normal;
              font-weight: 500;
          }

          :host([theme~="my-custom-grid"]:not([reordering])) [part~="row"][selected] [part~="body-cell"]:not([part~="details-cell"]):nth-child(2n) {
              background: linear-gradient(var(--color-grey-row-salesrank), var(--color-grey-row-salesrank)) repeat;
          }

          :host([theme~="my-custom-grid"]:not([reordering])) [part~="row"][selected] [part~="body-cell"]:not([part~="details-cell"]) {
              background: linear-gradient(var(--color-grey-row-selected), var(--color-grey-row-selected)) repeat;
          }
      </style>
  </template>
  ```

Comment: Please add some jsbin or codepen example.

Comment: Hi. Dont know why you need a fiddle for a simple grid with a scrollbar but as you wish :) https://jsfiddle.net/2aj4vtyt/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
:host([theme~="my-custom-grid"]) {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}

:host([theme~="my-custom-grid"]) #fixedsizer,
:host([theme~="my-custom-grid"]) #outerscroller {
    display: none;
}

:host([theme~="my-custom-grid"]) #table {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

vaadin-grid has two container elements with scrollbar at the same time, so we have to hide two scrollbars.

Try to do next:

```
#table {
    right: -15px;   //we can't set overflow:hidden here as we'll can't to scroll
}

#outerscroller {
    right: -15px;   // and here too
}

#scroller {
    left: -15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

vaadin-grid {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is only for vertical scrollbar, so you will need to do the same things to hide horizontall scroll. Good luck!

Comment: even though this solution is hacky and not `clean` I tried it.... and it had no effect at all.

Answer (score 0):

I did it programmatically on the ready event by doing:

```
var grid = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#reportGrid');// your id

grid.$.table.style.overflowX="hidden";
```

hope it could help because I was becoming crazy trying with the template style.